# service save failed without change

Tags: wso2

i'm stuck in this problem from many days in wso2 governance registry version 4.1.1
After promoting a service to development state from configuration (a new state that i've defined in my custom lifecycle) i'm trying to save the service.
If i dont't make any changes to content details, saving procedure fail returning this error message
" Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/{serviceName}"
on the other hand modifying at least one field in service content, no error appears.
I found this fix 
http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/carbon-commits/2012-January/053562.html
but seems not fix my problem.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you send us full stack trace please.